# Does lithium grease damage plastics such as ABS & PBT?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers

I have read that petroleum-based greases damage plastics due to the petroleum-derived nature of most plastics. However, I have seen lithium grease being used in electronics such as the gears in CD players. What is determines the resistibility of certain plastics to petroleum-based grease?

Comment: Usually, no chemistry is involved. (Some) plastics may (partly) dissolve or swell in contact with organic solvents and also grease. This alters material properties, such as mechanical strenghth, optical appearance etc. This does not occur for all combinations of plastics and grease.